# Gmail API get messages where there are contacts included in the CC

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I'm trying to get all the messages where:

- I cced someone
- Someone has cced somebody to a message inbound to me.

I looked in the [advanced search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en) for some guides, but all I can see is specifying a contact to a `cc:` search operator, [reference](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en#:%7E:text=Specify%20a%20recipient%20who%20received%20a%20copy). 
There's really no docs for searching all messages where there are someone who's being cced to a message. Be it `SENT` or `INBOX`

It would be good if someone can provide an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- You want to list all messages where there `Cc` header is populated.
- There's no way to directly filter out by whether any `cc` is present, just for a certain email address (i.e. `cc:my_user@my_domain.com`). That's the case for the API as well as the UI.

#### Solution:

In that case, I'd suggest the following worflow:

1. Call [users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) to list all messages in your mailbox. You'll have to handle pagination at this point, if you want to retrieve all messages, using `pageToken` and `nextPageToken`.
2. For each message `id`, call [users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) to get the corresponding message (only `id` and `threadId` are returned from `list`).
3. Filter out messages that don't have the `Cc` [header](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#Message.Header).

#### Code sample:

For example, in Apps Script you could do something like this (pagination is not implemented in this sample):

```
function getCcMessages() {
  const userId = "me";
  const { messages } = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userId);
  const messageIds = messages.map(m => m["id"]);
  const optionalArgs = {
    format: "METADATA",
    metadataHeaders: "Cc" 
  }
  const ccMessages = messageIds.map(id => {
    const message = Gmail.Users.Messages.get(userId, id, optionalArgs);
    return message;
  }).filter(m => {
    const headers = m["payload"]["headers"];
    return headers;
  });
  return ccMessages;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I did too. basically, used the metadataHeaders and retrieve the `Cc` headers. So, I will mark this as the answer.